# Twitter Bootstrap Togglable tabs menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm trying to modify the Twitter Bootstrap Togglable tabs (tab.js) . Instead of using text, I am using an image (and another for an active state).  I would like to use a second image every time the *li* is "active" and/or clicked.

I have a working demo below, but when the *li* is active or clicked, the "active image" is hidden underneath the first image. I would like the "active" image to completely replace the first image.

[bootply demo of tabs](http://bootply.com/83428)

Here is how I have an "active *li*" setup

```
<li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/jZQceNz.png" class="img-responsive" alt="OurStory_gradientbox" height="126" width="222"></a></li>
```

The active image I am using is in the css (line # 25 )

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if that's what you want but a simple way to do it would be to add this to your CSS rules :

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a > img{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

With that the image on top of your active one will become invisible. You can see it in action there http://bootply.com/83439

Comment: I'm over-complicating it. I just need the 3 images I'm using in the nav menu to display a second image for the active/click state. The second image just has a darker color and border (I want to use an image instead of css)